# Advanced Excel Fiitering

Tags: excel

Please I need help removing any row with Total, Subtotal, On-budget or Off-budget but also for all the missing values in the Department column, I want to fill them in with the value of Total, Subtotal, On-budget or Off-budget. Here is the link to the data
:https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2017/assets/hist03z2.xls